# Is there a way to change the element of an XML that has the same tag but different elements using elementtree

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

So I have an XML which has multiple lines for Date of birth but the elements differ.
For example in my XML I have the lines:

```
<date-of-birth>12-3-1998</date-of-birth>
<date-of-birth>12-3-1998</date-of-birth>
<date-of-birth>12-3-1998</date-of-birth>
<date-of-birth>31-7-1941</date-of-birth>
<date-of-birth>23-11-1965</date-of-birth>
```

I would like to change the lines that only have the DOB `"12-3-1998"` to have the DOB `"14-11-2001"` and keep the others unchanged but I am struggling to find out how to do this without changing them all or changing none.

I tried doing this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_tree = ET.parse(TestXML.xml)
root = xml_tree.getroot()
for DOB in root.findall(".//{*}12-3-1998"):
     DOB.text = "14-11-2001"
ET.tostring(root)
```

But my `root.findall(".//{*}12-3-1998")` doesn't find anything so all of my DOBs stay the same

I tried to do the following but it changes all of my DOB elements and I only want to change the ones which have "12-3-1998":

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_tree = ET.parse(TestXML.xml)
root = xml_tree.getroot()
for DOB in root.findall(".//{*}date-of-birth"):
     DOB.text = "14-11-2001"
ET.tostring(root)
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to filter on the specific DOB I want to change whether it is using elementtree and/or another Python library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """
<data>
    <date-of-birth>12-3-1998</date-of-birth>
    <date-of-birth>12-3-1998</date-of-birth>
    <date-of-birth>12-3-1998</date-of-birth>
    <date-of-birth>31-7-1941</date-of-birth>
    <date-of-birth>23-11-1965</date-of-birth>
</data>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)

for dob in root.findall("date-of-birth"):
    if dob.text == "12-3-1998":
        dob.text = "14-11-2001"

print(ET.tostring(root).decode("utf-8"))
```

Prints:

```xml
<data>
    <date-of-birth>14-11-2001</date-of-birth>
    <date-of-birth>14-11-2001</date-of-birth>
    <date-of-birth>14-11-2001</date-of-birth>
    <date-of-birth>31-7-1941</date-of-birth>
    <date-of-birth>23-11-1965</date-of-birth>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Andrej's answer you can use `iter()` and `replace()`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

xml_snipped = """
<root>
<date-of-birth>12-3-1998</date-of-birth>
<date-of-birth>12-3-1998</date-of-birth>
<date-of-birth>12-3-1998</date-of-birth>
<date-of-birth>31-7-1941</date-of-birth>
<date-of-birth>23-11-1965</date-of-birth>
</root>"""

f = StringIO(xml_snipped)

root = ET.parse(f).getroot()

for dob in root.iter():
    dob.text = dob.text.replace("12-3-1998", "14-11-2001")

ET.indent(root, space="  ")
ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <date-of-birth>14-11-2001</date-of-birth>
  <date-of-birth>14-11-2001</date-of-birth>
  <date-of-birth>14-11-2001</date-of-birth>
  <date-of-birth>31-7-1941</date-of-birth>
  <date-of-birth>23-11-1965</date-of-birth>
</root>
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you